# Setting fixed Matplotlib figure size height

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting line chart using below code and want fixed height of plot but some how height of first plot is bigger than the other two. Need help to fix height of first plot. Goal is to have consistent fixed height for all plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import pandas as pd


def show_graph(data, file_name):
    plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.plot(
        data.index,
        data[data.columns[0]],
        marker='o',
        linewidth=3,
        markersize=8
    )
    plt.title("test", pad=12)
    plt.savefig(file_name, bbox_inches="tight")


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[7.0, 12.0, 2.0, 6.0, 6.0, 10.0, 2.0], columns=["value"])
show_graph(df, "first")
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 48.0, 0.0, 100.0], columns=["value"])
show_graph(df1, "second")
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 48.0, 0.0, 100.0], columns=["value"])
show_graph(df2, "third")
```

[image: First Figure]
[image: Second Figure]
[image: Third Image]

Comment: They are of same height only. Can you share the screenshot?

Comment: @Pygirl Please check attached images

Answer (score 0):

For me too, all of them were of same height. Try the following solution and see if it works for you.

```
def show_graph(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[10, 8])
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    ax.plot(
        data.index,
        data[data.columns[0]],
        marker='o',
        linewidth=3,
        markersize=8
    )
    plt.title("test", pad=12)
    plt.show()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the "whole world" of data and no dynamic behavior is needed, then if I understood you correctly, use this (addition of [ylim](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html)):

```
def show_graph(data):
    plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.plot(
        data.index,
        data[data.columns[0]],
        marker='o',
        linewidth=3,
        markersize=8
    )
    plt.ylim(0, 105)
    plt.title("test", pad=12)
    plt.show()
```